# "yet" vs. "already" with present perfect

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect

'Yet' and 'already' are often used with Present Perfect.

Which of them is preferred in sentences like this:

> Is your father here **yet** (or already?)? Yes, he has just come.

'Yet' is used to say that it is expected that something has happened and used in negative sentences and in questions, so in the sentence above it seems that it is used correctly.

But is it possible to use **already** in this question? Would **already** sound naturally here?

Comment: serge, I'm not sure, but "I has just come" is not correct there. Perhaps "I is just came" is better, but I hope some expert shed a bit of light :)

Comment: No, Carlo, I'm afraid both "I has just come" and moreover "I is just came" are not correct. It should be "I have just come" and "I just came".

Comment: Serge, sorry I'm a bit confused yet, but I'm learning. However, if the mistery is revealed you could edit the question :)

Comment: Carlo, I'm becoming confused too :) What exactly do you want me to correct?

Comment: Serge, sorry I'm still confused about how to use the present perfect and when I read the question I have had the impression there was a mistake :)

Comment: I don't see what Present Perfect has to do with the *yet/aready* issue. The reply in the above example could just as well be *"Yes, he arrived five minutes ago"*. Or even *"Yes, he arrived last week"* - it makes no difference *how long ago*, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is illustrated by imagining a blind passenger asking the car driver...

> 1: "Are we there yet?"
>    2: "Are we there already?"

...where the different implications are...

> (1) *it's [already] been a long journey, and I hope we've finally arrived [we should have].*
>    (2) *it's not been a long journey [yet], but surprisingly it seems we might already have arrived.*

To put it another way, in such contexts, ***yet*** = after so **much** time, ***already*** = after so **little** time. That's to say, use *yet* if you were expecting/hoping for *earlier*, or *already* if you were expecting *later* (but not *yet*).

---

Note that both words can be used in contexts where either or both of *expectation/likelihood* and *hope/desire* are involved. In practice it makes no difference if an impatient child on a long car journey asks *"**Are** we there yet?"* or *"**Aren't** we there yet?"*. But in other contexts, framing such questions in the negative often comes across as rude/impatient/accusatory, rather than a neutral request for information.

Answer (score 3):

While both are grammatically valid sentences they mean different things, and *yet* is surely what you'd want to use in this case.

> Person A: Is your father here yet?
>
> Person B: Yes, he has just *arrived*.

(Note the use of *arrived* rather than *come*; *come* needs an additional "from where", ex. "Yes, he has just come home from work.")

When using *yet* here, you're asking a question: *is your father here*. You don't know the answer, and you expect a yes or no reply.

It's a bit different when you use *already*:

> Person A: *sees or hears something that makes them realize the father is here, but they didn't expect the father to arrive until later*
>
> Person A: Is your father here already?

In this case the question is a rhetorical one; Person A is aware that the father is there, but is surprised by this fact. So they state that the father is there *already*, as opposed to later on. They don't expect an answer, because they already know. This is just a way of expressing surprise.