# have you subscribed [yet, already]

Tags: present-perfect

I told my brother to subscribe a sport. And, I am still waiting for his reply. And if I want to know whether he has subscribed or not;  I can tell him:

> Have you subscribed it yet?
> Have you already subscribed?

Or

> Have you subscribed?

To me the first is better because I do not know until now if he has subscribed. But I don't know the real difference between the three.
And on the other hand, some people could say "did you subscribed?"

So I'm a little lost...

Comment: The 'it' should not be present in "Have you subscribed it yet?"

Comment: Also, I don't think you are using the word *subscribe* correctly, or at least you are not using it in a way familiar to me.  Is your brother signing up for a class, or joining a team, or subscribing to watch it on television, or something else?

Comment: See the following (as well as several other questions on this site dealing with "yet" vs. "already"): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/yet-vs-already-with-present-perfect

Comment: @stangdon subscribe for me , was to join a team, a group, what should I used?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan ok un understand that [already] is not appropriate. [Yet] is correct. And [have you subscribed?] Is correct but not specific to now. To finish [did you subscribe] is correct only in AE? Is that true?

Comment: @Meedfried If he is joining a team, I would say (in American English) that you told him to **sign up for** it.  We *subscribe to* a magazine or newspaper.